# I need a regular expression to match dates with the format of Month DD, YYYY

Tags: regex

So I ran into a need for regular expressions to match the American format of Month DD, YYYY in order to remove parentheses from the dates on a site I'm working on.  I hadn't seen much useful information while googling, so I thought I'd post both the question, as well as the solution I came up with here.

Format started as such:

(January 1, 2013)

And needed to be:

January 1, 2013

ADDING to question text: The original solution I came up with:

```
\(([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)\W+([0-9]{2})\W+([0-9]{4})\)
```

and the chosen answer, which I liked more than my own:

```
\(([A-Z][a-z]+\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4})\)
```

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: @AndyLester Hi Andy, you seem to be a little confused.  I actually did write code myself, its actually one of the answers below.  I posted in the question "both the question, as well as the solution I came up with here."  I've already answered the question, but have not checked my own answer as the answer because I was sure there was probably a better one out there.

Comment: @AndyLester I see why there was confusion, that was my fault.  I should have probably posted my answer in the question above as well.  I'll keep that in mind if I write any more answers to my future questions.

Comment: @gustavohenke Thank you.  I don't ask questions often, so I'm still a touch new to the standards here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\(([A-Z][a-z]+\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4})\)
```

use group 1 to get the value without parentheses.

See on [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/SWG7XLCqDW).

Comment: That is a lot easier to read than I came up with!  I actually posted because I knew there had to be a better way, so I'm glad you answered!  Enjoy your "Answered!" status.

Answer (score 2):

```
\\(([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+)\W+([0-9]{2})\W+([0-9]{4})\\)
```

To break it down:

`\\\(` -escapes the opening parentheses

`(`  -starts the point in which I'm "saving" the Month to use in the replace

`[A-Z]{1}` -Matches a single capital letter (since months are pro-nouns and all)

`[a-z]+`  -this is to match the rest of the word

`)`  -ends the point in which I'm "saving" the Month to use in the replace

`\W+` -using this to target the empty space between the name of the Month and the following numbers

`([0-9]{2})` -matches and "saves" any 2 digit number, this would by my DD

`\W+`  -match space between DD, and YYYY

`([0-9]{4})`  -matches my year, YYYY

`\\)` -escapes closing parentheses

Comment: +1 for the effort of explaining it.

Comment: @Yossarian Thanks for the edit.  I hadn't caught that the special characters didn't go through the way I had intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
\((\w+ [0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{2,4})\)
```

If PHP:

```
preg_replace('#\((\w+ [0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{2,4})\)#','$1',$dateStr);
```